# C problem about Compiler and Memory Theory

Tags: c, memory, buffer-overflow, instructions

Without calling any "call" or "jump" function, we need to get a output in order of "this is the first" then "this is the second.". In my opinion we need to use "bold" with the use of Memory and instructions. Also we cannot call the function of "study".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void study()
{
    printf("this is the second.\n");
}

void study2()
{
    int bold[4];
    // can only modify this section BEGIN
    // cant call study(), maybe use study(pointer to function)


    // can only modify this section END
    printf("this is the first\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    study2();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can modify the source code if this program?  How, to make it vulnerable to a buffer overflow of some sort?  You seem to be talking about assembly language (like "call" or "jump"), but you're talking about modifying the C source.  In C calling a function is a primitive operation, not something you need another function for.  e.g. `printf("this is the first\nthis is the second\n"); return;` isn't a "call function" it's a "print function".  It's not a function like `longjmp()` that calls yet another function or jumps somewhere else.  But I think that's not what you mean.

Comment: The location of a string literal has nothing to do with the address of the function. You'd need to somehow find the instructions that construct the argument list of `printf`, and find in that the address of the first argument.

Comment: @PeterCordes IIUC, they want to get that string and print it, without calling the function.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `bold` array would be relevant. But I've never gotten into writing exploits and buffer overflows, so maybe I'm naive about this.

Comment: A ROP attack isn't a matter of compiler *theory*, it's a matter of practical implementation details and asm for a specific build by a specific compiler version for a specific ISA.  Presumably `bold[5] = 0x12345;` or something, if compiled without optimization, might produce asm that stores a new return address somewhere.  But it's compiler-visible undefined behaviour so modern compilers might just compile it to an x86 `ud2` (illegal intruction) or something.

Comment: @Barmar: I think the intent of the assignment is to write two new return addresses on the stack via out-of-bounds access to `bold[]` and then do a `return;` (to pop the lower of the two into program counter), with the two addresses being to `study()` and to the middle of `study2()`, somewhere after the `return;` statement you add in the middle.  (So it needs to be a conditional return like `if(!static_var++)`, otherwise dead code elimination would remove the `printf("first")`.)  This would still meet the requirements if "call or jump function" was supposed to be "statement" or "instruction".

Comment: That won't even compile, there's no function called `secret` in your code.  Also, how would that help?  It's just a function call via a function pointer with a constant initializer, no different from just doing `secret()`.  If you can make function calls, do what I (and later Eric) suggested and just write a new call to printf with both strings, then return, so neither of the existing printf statement are reached.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry I meant &study. I want a output as "this is the first" then "this is the second.". However I need to use memory functions and instructions. I tried this code "void  (*array[1])();
    array[0] = &study;
    array[0]();" between the legal spaces of the code, however it printed vice versa.

Comment: Right, like I said, that's exactly equivalent to `study();`.  You either need to do some target-specific undefined behaviour stuff (basically write code that intentionally does a ROP attack on itself via buffer overflow), or you need to do more prints, or `atexit(study)` to arrange for `study` to be called after the end of main.  Or compile with an ancient GCC version that supports `-fwriteable-strings` and find and modify the string data in the `.data` section.  (Or with newer GCC, use linker options or `mprotect` to make all pages writeable.)

Comment: I was maybe over-complicating it earlier; we don't need to overwrite 2 return addresses, just the return address of `study2` with the address of `study`.  Neither way preserves stack alignment very easily, so might be hard to get right if compiling on a normal x86-64 system.  32-bit x86 is probably fine since some calling conventions don't require alignment, and in practice code rarely depends on it.  So would AArch64 since it pushes/pops in 16-byte chunks with `ldp` / `stp`.

Comment: It's unclear what type of challenge this is.  You tagged [buffer-overflow], which suggests that you need to construct some kind of exploit, but the attempt you described is just a syntactic workaround to avoid calling `study` directly via its name.  Is it required that `study()` be executed at all?

Comment: No [tag:compiler-construction] here. You are not constructing a compiler. Don't tag indiscrimately.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not what OP had in mind, yet macros do the trick.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void study() {
  printf("this is the second.\n");
}

void study2() {
  int bold[4];
  // can only modify this section BEGIN
  // Without calling any "call" or "jump" function, 
  #define F1 study
  #define F2 study2
  #define study2() F2(); F1();
  // can only modify this section END
  printf("this is the first\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  study2();
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
this is the first
this is the second.
```

---

Maybe violates <Also we cannot call the function of "study".>.  Depends on "we", if "we" is the portion of code between `BEGIN ... END`, it is OK.

Else if `"we"` is anywhere in code, than maybe a direct approach:

```
void study2() {
  int bold[4];
  // can only modify this section BEGIN
  #define printf(x) printf("this is the first\nthis is the second.\n")
  // can only modify this section END
  printf("this is the first\n");
}
```

---

[@Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77399108/c-problem-about-compiler-and-memory-theory/77399285?noredirect=1#comment136449735_77399285) suggests a 3rd way, where our modification does not call `study()`.

```
void study2() {
  int bold[4];
  // can only modify this section BEGIN
  atexit(study);
  // can only modify this section END
  printf("this is the first\n");
}
```

Comment: I like it; we're not calling `study()` from inside the BEGIN..END region.  If `study()` is not to be called at all, then it's pointless for it to exist in the source code.  (Unless they want it to be called via overwriting the return address of `study2` with the address of `study1` via undefined behaviour, perhaps on a system where stack pointer alignment by more than one stack slot isn't required.  e.g. typical 32-bit calling conventions for some mainstream ISAs like x86 and maybe ARM.  Those are also ones where pointer width is usually `sizeof(int)`, unlike x86-64.)

Comment: Another way to get `study` called without calling it ourselves is `atexit(study)`.  It will of course get called during the execution of the program, so it's the same question of semantics of "we" etc.  One downside to this is that `stdio.h` doesn't declare `atexit()`, so we're depending on implicit declaration being compatible with the actual `int atexit(void (*function)(void));` prototype.  (Which is the case in most mainstream calling conventions, and ISO C89 allows implicit declarations, with most compilers supporting it in later modes, too.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, these sorts of changing the executable are very implementation dependent and deserve a specific platform tag(s).

Comment: @PeterCordes Nice use of `atexit()`!

Comment: Exactly what I already commented under the question.  From the way the OP is reporting the kind of language the assignment specified, like messing with "memory", I think that *is* what they're supposed to be doing, so it's not a theoretical or portable thing, it depends on implementation details.

Comment: Wow, that's hideous!  Love it!

Comment: I get seasick when I see stuff like this. +1 :-)